# Duplicate rows are created after bulk create with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-2.7

I'm doing a bulk create to dump a lot of information into a database at once.  The information is layered - I create the top layer, then use the data as relationships for the next layer, etc.  I'm unable to use PostgreSQL, so I can't take advantage of its ability to return primary keys when doing a bulk create.

Instead, I create a UUID and stick it in with each layer, then use it to grab the rows I've just made so that I can use them for the next layer.  A dumbed-down model looks like this:

```
class Container(Component):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bulk_insert_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
```

and the bulk create/query for what I just created looks like this:

```
bulk_insert_id = uuid.uuid4()
requirements = []
for requirement, child in zip(self.component['children'], self.children):
    r = models.Container(
        parent=self.db,
        bulk_insert_id=bulk_insert_id,
    )
    child.db_id = r
    requirements.append(r)
models.Container.objects.bulk_create(requirements)
requirements = models.Container.objects.filter(bulk_insert_id=bulk_insert_id)
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I go to actually use these elements, I'm finding duplicates of them.  It's as if a copy is inserted by the bulk create, and then another copy is created when I access/save data to it for the first time.  Here's an example screenshot from SSMS:

[image: SSMS view of duplicate rows]

As you can see from the image above, the last two rows are copies of the first two rows.  Any ideas as to where these duplicates are coming from?

Tools:

- SQL Server
- Django 1.11
- django-pyodbc-azure 1.11.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong - I saved a stale link to the container before bulk creating it.

Bulk creating it put one copy of the row in the database.   Then, when I used the stale link (and saved), that put in a second copy of the row - this one without any children pointing up towards it.

The solution was to move the stale link until after the bulk create, like this:

```
bulk_insert_id = uuid.uuid4()
requirements = []
for requirement in self.children:
    r = models.Container(
        parent=self.db,
        bulk_insert_id=bulk_insert_id,
    )
    requirements.append(r)
    # don't use the link here, it will be stale when we make the requirements
models.Container.objects.bulk_create(requirements)
requirements = models.Container.objects.filter(bulk_insert_id=bulk_insert_id)
# new stuff
for requirement, child in zip(requirements, self.children):
    child.db_id = requirement
```